# Filtering Nested Objects in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index which has the following mapping

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "data": {
            "date_detection": false,
            "_all": {
                "enabled": false
            },
            "properties": {
                "DocumentId": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "SubscriptionId": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "AccountId": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "SubscriptionStartDateTime": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                },
                "SubscriptionEndDateTime": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                },
                "DateWiseMetrics": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "Date": {
                            "type": "date",
                            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
                        },
                        "Usage": {
                            "type": "long"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is

1. For a given account id, start date, and end date find all active subscriptions with in that period
2. Find the usage for that given period for all the active subscriptions found in step 1.

For example,

If start date = "2017-08-01 00:00:00" and end date = "2017-09-01 00:00:00", i will find all active subscriptions in that period and then i want to see the daily usage of those subscriptions from 2017-08-01 till 2017-09-01.

I was able to get the active subscriptions (Step 1) correct, but not getting correct values when i filter further by Date in the nested object (Step 2).

```
{
   "_source" : false,
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  { "term" : { "AccountId" : 290804220029 } },
                  {
                     "nested": {
                        "path": "DateWiseMetrics",
                        "filter":

                              { "range" : { "DateWiseMetrics.Date": { "gte": "2017-01-01", "lte": "2017-08-01" }  }

                        }, "inner_hits" : {}
                     }
                  }
               ],
               "must_not" : [
                   { "range" : { "SubscriptionStartDateTime": { "gt": "2017-08-01 00:00:00" }  }},
                   { "range" : { "SubscriptionEndDateTime": { "lt": "2017-01-01 00:00:00" }  }}

               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }

}
```

I think the way i am filtering nested objects is wrong. Please help.

Also, is there a way to show values of few parent items ( for eg: accountid, subscriptionid) along with inner hit results? What i observed is that when you add *"_source" : false* the parent elements don't appear anymore.

Thanks

Comment: What is the version you are using?

Comment: It you are using the old way. Have you tried this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-nested-query.html (the equivalent for filter)